# How to parse html<attribute>String in flutter

Tags: html, flutter, parsing

i want to get "spname" attribute from this html string

```
<ul>
   <li class='expanded' data-icon='folder_docs.gif' id='fol_1' onclick='getli(this.id,0)' dcr='7/26/2017 2:42:47 PM' spname='Documents'>
      Documents
      <ul>
         <li class='' id='fol_20'onclick='getli(this.id,0)' f_pertype='2' dcr='7/5/2019 10:29:02 AM' is_Wr='True' own='13781' spname='test'>
            test
            <ul>
               <li class='' id='fol_27'onclick='getli(this.id,0)' f_pertype='2' dcr='9/3/2020 9:10:26 AM' is_Wr='True' own='13781' spname='test2'> test2</li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='' id='fol_22'onclick='getli(this.id,0)' f_pertype='2' dcr='7/5/2019 4:13:16 PM' is_Wr='True' own='13781' spname='SP'> SP</li>
         <li class='' id='fol_26'onclick='getli(this.id,0)' f_pertype='2' dcr='11/11/2019 10:54:00 AM' is_Wr='True' own='2021' spname='IT Files'> IT Files</li>
         <li class='' id='fol_28'onclick='getli(this.id,0)' f_pertype='2' dcr='9/3/2020 9:20:55 AM' is_Wr='True' own='13781' spname='test3'> test3</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I save this html as string and I parse it

```
print("attachmentlist:"+response.toString());
var documents=response.toString();
print(documents);
var parsdocuments=parse(documents).getElementsByTagName('li');
```

i want to print "spname" attribute as list but i cant git it.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of the parse method?

Comment: thank you for response , this is the output of printing element by tage name 'li' as above code : [<html li>, <html li>, <html li>, <html li>, <html li>, <html li>]

Comment: actually i want to know how to reach the 'spname' attribute or any attribute in this html string

Comment: Have you checked this Medium post on the Dart package that you are using? https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-html-in-dart-with-html-package-cd43c29cc460

Comment: yes , but cant get what i want,